# 1st row is not being from database in php

Tags: php, mysql

For some reason I'm having a problem retrieving data from my database. It leaves off the first item being listed.

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM students WHERE (year = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['year']) . "') and ( branch= '" . mysql_real_escape_string(($_SESSION['branch'])). "') ");


$data=mysql_fetch_array( $sql );

print "<table>"
while($data = mysql_fetch_array( $sql )) 
 { 

 Print "<tr><td>".$data['idno']." </td><td>".$data['name'] . " </td></tr>";
 } 
print "</table>"
```

Please help me with this. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don't use the `mysql_*` functions, they are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ) . Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you cannot decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you want to learn, [here is a good PDO-related tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the following line:

```
$data=mysql_fetch_array( $sql );
```

The call to [`mysql_fetch_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) moves the internal pointer to the next row, thus you are getting all rows except the first in your `while` loop.

You could also reset the internal pointer with [`mysql_data_seek`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-data-seek.php).

```
mysql_data_seek ($sql, 0); // 0 for first row
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you use mysql_fetch_array one time before your while. The first call will get the first result, and then you will enter into the while loop. the `$data`variable will erase the first result to be assigned by the second result and then the third, the fourth and so on.
Because of this call before the while loop, you will always avoid the first result